# unique container for template class

Tags: c++, templates

I have an algorithm (not preseted here) which takes as input different parameters (int, float, vectors).
My idea of design was to have an container which holds all these differents parameters. 

To achive this, I have a base class Parameter and a derivated template class TypeParameter.
These parameters will be holded in a container.

The design is presented below:

```
    #pragma once

#include <utility>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace parameter
{
    /*
        Interface for parameter
    */
    class Parameter
    {
    public:
        Parameter() {}
        Parameter(std::string param_name) : name(param_name) {}
        Parameter(const Parameter&& other) noexcept : name(std::move(other.name)) {}
        virtual ~Parameter() {}

        inline const std::string get_name() { return name;  }

    private:
        std::string name;
    };

    /*

    */
    template<class T>
    class TypeParameter
        : public Parameter
    {
    public:
        TypeParameter(std::string param_name, T new_value) : Parameter(param_name), value(new_value) {}
        TypeParameter(const TypeParameter&& other) noexcept : Parameter(std::move(other)), value(std::move(other.T)) {}

        inline const T get_value() { return value; }

    private:
        T value;
    };

    /*
        Container for parameters
    */

    class ParameterSet
    {
    public:
        ParameterSet() {}

        void add(std::unique_ptr<Parameter> param) { data.push_back(std::move(param)); }

    private:
        std::vector <std::unique_ptr<Parameter>> data;
    };

} //namespace parameter
```

The main is:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "Parameter.h"

using parameter::TypeParameter;
using parameter::Parameter;
using parameter::ParameterSet;

void foo(std::unique_ptr<Parameter> p)
{
    std::cout << p->get_value(); // ERROR
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    TypeParameter<int> *iparam = new TypeParameter<int>("ee", 3);
    std::unique_ptr<Parameter> p = std::make_unique <TypeParameter<int>>("foo", 3);


    foo(std::move(p));

    ParameterSet param_set;
    param_set.add(std::unique_ptr<Parameter>(iparam));
    param_set.add(std::move(p));

    getchar();
}
```

My problem is I cannot get the value without a cast.

Hence, my question is how do I cast the unique_ptr from a Parameter class to derived TypeParameter.
Is there another way to design the container?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sounds like you want a container of [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

Comment: If you have a limited set of parameter types you want to handle `std::variant` with `std::visit` might be the way you want to go.

Comment: Or add virtual methods to `Parameter` as `virtual void print() const = 0`

Comment: I don't see what can I do with `virtual void print()`. I need to get the value of the parameter.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux or [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any). At any rate, a cast is necessary

Comment: in almost all cases, you have a design flaw here. when `foo` only knows your base class, it only knows your base class. when it's necessary to "upcast" to concrete types, you shouldn't use polymorphism. you code is neither extendable, open-closed, or any other paradigm used in the object-oriented world.

Comment: @tupanu: `void foo(const Parameter& p)
{
    p.print();
}` would do the job with `virtual` `Parameter::print`. you don't necessary require value with getter, but generic actions.

Comment: BTW, you might be surprised as you move `p` twice.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to reinvent the wheel. There are a couple of classes you can use from the standard library:

### [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

As suggested by the comments, `variant` is a type-safe union of a pre-defined set of data types, which you put in the templates argument of `variant`.
For example, a `std::variant<int,float,double>` can hold any value of type `int`, `float`, or `double`, but nothing else.

To use the stored value, you can either use the visitor pattern with the `std::visit()` function. Other functions allow you to know which of the preset types is stored in the variable (`index()`) and to extract the value from it (using `get()`). If you try to extract the value of the wrong type, the `get()` function throws an exception

### [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)

is another utility that can hold different data types. As opposed to `variant`, you don't have to know the types at compile-time. Basically, it stores a `void*` to the data with a `typeinfo` to remember its original type. You can then use `any_cast` to cast the variable back to its original type. Just like `variant`, an exception is thrown when trying to cast to the wrong type.

These two classes are available in C++ 17. If these features are not available to you, they were also included in boost (respectively [`boost:variant`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/variant.html) and [`boost:any`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/any.html))

You can store the set of values in a standard library container, e.g. in a `std::vector<std::variant<int,float,double>>` or a `std::vector<std::any>>`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to `std::variant`/`std::any` is the old way polymorphism:

```
class Parameter
{
public:
    Parameter(const std::string& param_name) : name(param_name) {}
    virtual ~Parameter() = default;

    const std::string& get_name() const { return name;  }

    virtual void printValue() const = 0;
    // Other virtual methods

private:
    std::string name;
};

template<class T>
class TypeParameter : public Parameter
{
public:
    TypeParameter(const std::string& name, const T& t) : Parameter(name), value(t) {}

    // Non virtual method when we don't access it by base class.
    const T& get_value() const { return value; }

    void printValue() const { std::cout << value; }

private:
    T value;
};
```

And then your

```
void foo(const Parameter& p)
{
    std::cout << p.get_value(); // ERROR
}
```

becomes

```
void foo(const Parameter& p)
{
    p.print();
}
```

If you don't want to add many virtual methods to `Parameter`, then [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) can help, but then you have to know each derived types.